# Windows 8 Internet Explorer 10 does not display Hebrew correctly

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, multilingual

When I switch my keyboard from ENG to HEBrew IE 10 does not display the keys I enter correctly.

For example, when I write 'hands' in IE 10 it is displayed as  '׃' while it should be 'ידיימ'

Anyone else experiencing this and even better, anyone found a solution or is this something a next update should fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that removing and adding Hebrew in Clock, Language, and Region -> Language did the trick and resolved this issue.